# docker supposedly installed but not runnable

Tags: docker

If I do a docker command like

```
docker -version
```

I get the error that docker is not installed and that I can do sudo apt-get install docker to install it. If I do this, it says that docker is the latest version. Do I need to set some kind of path to the binary to get it to run?

If I do `which docker`, there is no answer.

Comment: Whats your OS? Ubuntu? Did you follow the instructions at https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/ including the part about removing older versions? And I think it should be either `docker version` or `docker --version`.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to the question.

Apparently there is a package called "docker" which has nothing to do with docker the container software which is actually `docker-ce`. The application I had installed was the fake docker, not the container-ware.

To install docker-ce there is [a process given on Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-16-04) which can be used.

.

Comment: Docker [provide instructions for Ubuntu](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/)